# How do i call an api in flutter to another dart

Tags: rest, api, flutter

please i have created an API with staff data in it. i have created an app with flutter in that when an employee enters his staff id in the text-field and presses the search button the api should be called and display the data. any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the API via HTTP requests. For this, you would like to use an HTTP client package.

The [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) or [DIO](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

The response has then to be presented to the UI. I think there are tons of tutorials that you can follow along.

One example would be the [Fetch data from the internet](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Dio` package which give you a lot of functionalities and examples :

[Dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)